# How to refer an element using document.getElementById when id is not set for the element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input element as below.

```
<input type="text" name="emailId" size="30" value="" />
```

A third party JavaScript will add a `class`to this element for some tracking purpose. The third party is using the below code (loaded from cdn) to add the class to element. I have to send the `id`of input element as a parameter to the third party code.

```
var myObject = document.getElementById(objId);
if (myObject) {
if (myObject.className != "") {
myObject.className += " newclass";
} else {
myObject.className = "newclass";
};
```

};

But, unfortunately the input element doesn't have an `id`currently and I am not able to alter my code for now for some reason. 
The question is, is there any way to set the the class for the input element by passing `objId`in some format like using parent element id or form name etc?

Answer (score 2):

That is simply not possible. No ID, no `getElementById`.

However, you could use other methods to grab the element.

`document.querySelector("input[name='email']")` or `querySelectorAll` if you need multiple.

Comment: Assigning the class is done by third party code as OP said, which cannot be altered. that means he has to provide id to them, and for that he has to modify the HTML.

Comment: The code is from third party cdn. I am not able to alter

Comment: As far as I understand @user3600885 you have no option but modify HTML to include id in element.

Comment: @RahulR. hence my first bit where it's impossible to use `getElementById` without an ID. Do pay attention.